# Automation tools for react native mobile apps

Tags: python, react-native, mobile, automation

I need to automate mobile apps which are react native apps . Can somebody suggest what are good tools to automate these apps ? I used appium(python) for testing mobile apps uptill now .

Can I use appium for testing react native apps as well?

Or can somebody please suggest tool/technology to test react native applications . Also If there is any tool which support python to write tests for react native apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use appium !

I did research on React Native dedicated tools and it turns out there are plenty of frameworks that allow for writing one code for both platforms:

- [Appium](http://appium.io/)
- [Cavy](https://github.com/pixielabs/cavy)
- [Detox](https://github.com/wix/detox)

More Information

- Unit testing components ([Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest)).
- Shallow-render testing components ([enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme)).
- Testing within your native environment, using native JS hooks ([Appium](http://appium.io/)).
- Testing completely within your native environment ([XCTest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest)).

Comment: Appium is great, i can vouch for that

Comment: @DanielSaggo yeah for sure !